# In Unity: how can I get the precise diameter of the cross section of an imported mesh?

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

For a simulation, I imported a mesh structure into my Unity project. This mesh consists of triangles and cannot easily be modelled by spheres/ cubes etc.
I am wondering, if there is a way to get the diameter of the cross section of the mesh (which is a tubular structure).
So far, I tried to get this diameter by adapting the size of cubes so this cube ends up roughly fitting the diameter of the mesh (so using it like a measuring tape)
Is there a better tool to do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In what way does your cube-as-measuring-tape method fall short of your needs? In what way should answers try to improve on this approach?

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be? Would simply getting the extends of the bounding box be a "good enough" solution?